# Which is correct: "...as a new..." or "...as new..."?

Tags: grammar

I've been having this discussion for a few months now: should I write "the molecule has been identified as new anti-inflammatory drug" or "the molecule has been identified as ***a*** new anti-inflammatory drug"?

I believe the second option is correct, but English is not my native language, and I can't find a rule to justify my opinion. Is there any rule that states the requirement of the article?

Sorry if this is really obvious, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are correct. Our use of an adjective does *not* remove the need for a determiner (articles: "a", "an", or "the"; possessives: "my", "his", etc.; or demonstratives: "this", "that", etc.).

To put it simply, we **always** need a determiner *unless*:

- It a general noun with a number. "Three cats are outside."
- It is a name. "Sam is outside." (And some names need "the", like "the United States")
- It is a general, plural/non-count noun. "Cats are cute."

All other cases need a determiner, so if you don't have "my", "this", or such, you must have "a/an" for a general singular noun.

Comment: You can skip the first qualification since numbers are determiners. However, the list isn't quite complete. E.g. consider: "I am king of this castle." - the word *king* is just a bare noun (no determiner) and doesn't fit any of your exclusions, and yet the sentence isn't grammatically problematic. It might be better to (*positively*) answer the question with reference to the specifics of the OP's sentence, rather than (*negatively*) saying that the sentence fails to meet an exhaustive list of exceptions.

Comment: I included the numbers separately from the determiners because, unlike other determiners, they can be combined. Articles, possessives, and demonstratives are mutually exclusive. "The my car" is incorrect. "This his cat" is incorrect. "My two cats", however, is correct.

Comment: @Lawrence As for "king of this castle", that's more of a fossilized exception, and rather archaic to my ears. I would probably say, "I am *the* king of this castle." As for answering positively, the list of concrete cases where you *should* use a determiner is far more exhaustive than where you shouldn't.

Comment: No, not a list. Perhaps I can rephrase. Using a checklist carries the risk of the list being non-exhaustive. Further, it begs the question of how items got onto the list in the first place - which boils down to "that's just the way it is". It would be better to explain what the bare noun phrase represents and why it doesn't fit the sentence.

Comment: One should always use a determiner to increase the clarity of a noun. The only cases where we would not, is where the noun is both general and plural/uncountable. I'm not sure why you have a hang up with this, as it is the standard way to present it. For example, here's the article on determiners from the British Council (for learning English): https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers  It states simply that "a determiner comes before the noun phrase", and then provides a *single* exception of when it does not (general plural/uncount nouns).

Comment: As an aside, the same page also states that numbers are "quantifiers", and excludes them from the definition of "determiner".

Comment: I don't think the *britishcouncil* page is trying to say that determiners and quantifiers are mutually exclusive terms. Have a look at ODO's definition 1.1 for [quantifier](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quantifier) - it's a type of determiner. // About your 'hang up' comment - that's a little rude, and it misses my point.

Comment: I apologize if I came off as rude; it wasn't my intent. My point was simply that you are criticizing the standard way of presenting the information. Saying "always do X except in uncommon cases Y and Z" is how this is *usually* presented, and I don't understand why you are objecting to it.  Further, I din't mean to say that they *weren't* determiners, but rather, that official sources also don't include numbers in the definition of determiners, so I hardly feel required to do so, especially where it can cause additional confusion later.

Comment: Apology accepted. Your 'numbers can take other determiners' comment justified the inclusion of numbers in your list. The 'list' approach might work on [ell.se], but for an EL&U answer, I'd like to see a deeper discussion about *why* it's on the list, not merely *that* it's on your list. I think you have the depth to address this more satisfyingly to an audience the [tour] describes as "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". Anyhow, I'm not really adding anything new now, so I'll take this opportunity to bow out of this comment thread.